# Normal distribution filter layer for NN

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, keras

I am wondering if there is a layer in Keras (or any other way) to perform a weighted average according a normal distribution over an input array inside a model. The normal distribution parameters would be given from another model which is taking different inputs. This “layer” would be used on multiple arrays of inputs inside a larger model in which I am trying to optimize a final output (see the simplified example in the figure below).

I am currently trying to do the job of that “layer” with CNN and LSTM layers but I don’t get good results. I guess my input arrays are too big (1000 time steps) for the size of my dataset (40000 time steps).

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is the output, the mean of some values? Then how does standard deviation play into this to give the whole distribution? And then would you apply this to some values in lieu of max pooling?

Comment: The output (the 0.785 in the example) is the dot product of the input array and the normal distribution weights. The mean and standard deviation are the normal distribution parameters and are related to the time or the order of the values in the input array. In the example figure, the mean is at time 8 and the standard deviation is equal to 2 timesteps. Instead of that “normal distribution layer”, I have tried different arrangements of lstm, conv and maxpool layers but I could not get any good results.

Comment: How do you get the normal distribution weights that you dot with your input column vector?

Comment: That's what I’m trying to determine. I am looking for a way to do that inside a model. The application behind this is that I have a time lag between an input and an output and mixing effect in a process, but the time lag and mixing depend on another set of inputs (for example levels in buffer tanks). I want to be able to get the average input at the right place in time given the other inputs that affect time lag and mixing.

Comment: How did you get the weights that gave you 0.785?

Comment: It's a calculation in Excel. It was just to show a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So how did you get those weights in Excel?